# What is usually the timeframe when a recruiter mention A.s.a.p?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment

I have been looking for a job for the past 5 months and I decided to go home for xmas since i was not getting any luck. I will be away for a month, and will come back Monday January 13th. I just received several calls for some job interviews saying I should start as soon as possible. In my understanding few companies hire during december. Will I have to cancel my vacation ? If i am selected how can i negotiate the start date with my employer ? The jobs are marketing related like account coordinator, market analyst, product manager etc.

Comment: Companies do hire in December, and many set up contractors to start in early January when their annual new budget takes effect.

Comment: Fiscal years can start anytime of the year, in US Government contracting the Government Fiscal year on October 1st can be a more important milestone. The real issue with December is that too many people are on vacation the last 1/3 of the month, making it hard to get all the approvals needed to make a decision and get a new person started.

Comment: Much of this month end/year end stuff is people trying to make their numbers.  In a lot of cases you can 'commit' in December but not start until January.  In other cases people have left critical jobs and they literally need you in there at 8:00 the next morning if not sooner. You'll have to judge their real intention from hints.  If they're not bothered by a request to start in January you're OK, if they wonder just how important it is for you to have Dec 24th off - I would suggest you be there the next day.

Answer (score 10):

ASAP can mean anything from 'we need you in the office the day you interview' to 'we won't wait for a 3 month notice period to finish with your previous employer'. The only way to know is to ask the companies that are interviewing. Some may be okay with a start date in late January, some may not. Ask, decide based on the information you get, live with the decision.

You can send a simple e-mail to the recruiter saying:

> I am planning on taking a vacation from December 20th to January 13th and will not be available for in person interviews or to start the job until after January 13th. Could you ask the companies when they plan to hold the interviews, and if successful when they would want me to start so I can determine whether to cancel my vacation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What the recruiter means when he or she says 'ASAP' is that he or she wants to receive the commission ASAP. They have every reason to play up the urgency of the position they are submitting you for and no reasons to delay it. They don't want to lend you time to look at other opportunities, or to have some other recruiter snatch you away. The 'ASAP' thing might be true, or it might just be a sales tactic. Just like with any other negotiation, you may never know, and the only way to be in a better position is to know more about the market.

That being said, in my experience, a lot of large companies do not hire in December. The reason is that a lot of the decision making people go on vacation, and it is hard to approve budgets for positions and line up interviews.